# How could you write the "if - then" logic for the game Yacht?

Tags: c++, if-statement

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacht_(dice_game)

I created 5 dice in my c++ program and they each roll random numbers from 1-6.
So if you get all 1's its really simple. It's just:

```
if (dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1 && dice3 == 1 && dice4 ==  1 && dice5 == 1)
{
int total = 50;
}
```

Also, summing all the dice is easy too. But how could you write the if-statement for "if two to four dice are the same then sum up those dice"?  Is there a simple way you could do that?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the rules of the game.

Comment: `dice1`, `dice2` etc is not very useful.... try `dice[x]` ;-)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays :/

Comment: It's worth adding limitations like that to the question. This is far easier using `vector` and the standard library than what it is with a mess of `if`

Comment: yeah, but there's a case where you can sum up all the dice

Comment: *I'm not allowed to use arrays* means that this is an assignment, which means that you're expected to do the work yourself to complete it. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything and your instructor gets a false impression about what you've learned.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use tables and make variable which count 1 in table.  Then u can compare it.